# Is there an atof equivalent in go?

Tags: go

When converting the string "3px" to a float, C is able to handle it but go does not. In go, is there a way to convert the longest valid prefix of a string to a float?

**C:**

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() { 
    printf("%f", atof("3px")); 
    // result: 3.0
    return 0;
}
```

**Go:**

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "strconv"

func main() {
    value, err := strconv.ParseFloat("3px", 64)
    fmt.Printf("%f, %v\n", value, err)
    // strconv.ParseFloat: parsing "3px": invalid syntax
}
```

Comment: Just strip the `px` part? Do you need to handle arbitrary non number suffix?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there is no way to convert the longest valid prefix of a string to a float. Value being converted should be valid. 
From Docs : If s is well-formed and near a valid floating point number, ParseFloat returns the nearest floating point number

https://golang.org/pkg/strconv/#ParseFloat

If you consider what C is doing, it is actually changing "3px" --> "3" first internally and then parsing. In Go, you have to explicitly strip out invalid chars before strconv can convert it.

Answer (score 2):

You can use **fmt.Sscan** it will extract only convertible part of your string

```
package main
import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    var s int
    fmt.Sscan("1px",&s)
    fmt.Println("Hello, playground",s)
}
```